# How can I remove the trim from this recessed light

Tags: recessed-lighting

I have this recessed light and I want to replace it with one of those LED all in one units. I can't figure out how to get the trim off.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Typically have springs that hook into the can, but I don't see any.  Could be a friction fit with the can.  Unless it's more or less permanently attached to the can and you're supposed to remove the can in its entirety.

Comment: Those indentations at 90-degree locations look like they're intended to snap over a nub ... so, yeah, I'd guess just pulling, maybe prying lightly at those spots to help ease it past the presumed bump.

Comment: might want to trace the circumference with a razor or exacto knife; sometimes paint grabs on the the lip and makes it hard/scare to pull down. It sometimes takes quite a bit of force to pull down, more than you expect. A decent whack with a screwdriver handle inside the cutout often helps, like ringing a bell; the jolt busts the paint/can bondage.

Comment: @dandavis or slip a paint scraper or tape knife between the flange and drywall to pry against, to avoid damaging the drywall if there's a lot of prying force.